# Why do I get undefined variable in an if statement?

Tags: matlab, if-statement, undefined

I get an error for undefined function or variable in the if statement (last line before last end), when I have already assigned the equalities.

```
l_min = nan(372,1);
A = randn(372,3);
B= randn(372,3);
for t=1:372
    min_ct = min( A(t,:));
      if min_ct == A(t,1);
        l = B(t,1);
        if min_ct == A(t,2);
            l = B(t,2);
        elseif min_ct == A(t,3);
            l = B(t,3);
        end
    end
    l_min(t) = l;
end
```

Could anyone help with this one?

Comment: You don't define `l` anywhere if your initial logic statement is false (`if min_ct == A(t,1)`), so `l_min(t) = l;` cannot be evaluated. In the future, it's much more helpful if you provide the *actual* error message, not your paraphrasing of it, since it tells the exact line where the issue is located.

Comment: It is impossible not to satisfy one of the criteria since the minimum value of A(1,:), for example, must be equal to some of the elements of A(1,:)!! All I want to get is the position of the minimum value for every iteration of t. For example if A(1,:) = [5 3 2], the minimum value is obvious that it is 2, which is the third element. I would like the code to pick the third element of a vector B(1,:) allocate it in the first position of the vector l_min.

Comment: I Imagine the second 'if' is actually meant to be an 'elseif' and one of the 'end's removed.

Comment: It's clearly not impossible because that's what's happening. You can [use the debugger](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) to convince yourself. You're never going to get to the inner criteria if `min_ct ~= A(t,1)`. I suggest you reevaluate your logic block.

Comment: @DanielAldrich Is correct: you need to change the 2nd `if` to `elseif`. You can also avoid the chain of `if`'s altogether by using the second output of `min` that gives you the index of the minimum found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish your task even without the `for` loop, using vectorization.

This is done by using the index output from the `min` function and specifying which direction you wish to determine the minimums in. Just replace everything in and after for loop with:

```
[~, ind] = min(A,[],2); % Determine minimum locations
bindex = sub2ind(size(B),1:size(B,1),ind') % Convert the subscripts to indices 
l_min = B(bindex)';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` logic is flawed, and should instead be

```
min_ct = min(A(t,:));
if min_ct == A(t,1);
    l = B(t,1);
elseif min_ct == A(t,2); % <-- Note thise is an *else*if
    l = B(t,2);
elseif min_ct == A(t,3);
    l = B(t,3);
end
```

Your weird half-indentation probably acted to confuse the flow of your logic.

---

Note: using `==` on doubles is prone to give you [unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab) as well, so you should consider using a better method for this anyway. In particular, the second output of the `min` function is designed to do exactly what you want!

Replace your `if` ladder with the following:

```
for t=1:372
    [~, min_idx] = min(A(t,:));
    l_min(t) = B(t, min_idx);
end
```